# Input doesn't match condition of if statement, but the statement executed

Tags: python, if-statement

Well, I'm making a console when if I type anything it will be saved in to `Console`. But when I tried, it is not what I expected. It supposed to fall in to `else` condition.

So I typed "vfdv" but it just go in to the second `elif`

Console output:

```
Console_
2024-01-13 18:24:10.022254
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Username\Proj\vscript\Console_>>   vfdv 
Session: 2024-01-13 18:24:10.022254 Exitting at:
2024-01-13 18:24:11.829106
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Username\Proj\vscript\Console_>
```

Here's the code:

```
print("Importing Required Libary...")
import sys
import os
import datetime
import logging
version = "1.0.0a"
session = datetime.datetime.now()
dirnow = os.getcwd()
os.system("cls")

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename="py_log.log",filemode="w",
                    format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")

print("Console_")
print(session)

while True:
    Console = None
    Console = input(dirnow + ">>")

    def Gettime():
        nsession = datetime.datetime.now() #Get Time.
        print(nsession) #Show
        nsession = None #Clear

    if Console == "SendTest":
        Gettime()
        print("Test suscessful, return.")

    elif Console == "Exit" or "exit" or "EXIT" or "end" or "End" or "END":
        print("Session: ", session, " Exitting at:")
        Gettime()
        sys.exit()
    
    elif Console == "Return" or "return" or "RETURN" or Console == "pass" or "Pass" or "PASS":
        pass

    else:
        print("Error at:")
        Gettime()
        print("No Such Command as " + Console + ", return")
        logging.info("ERR NOCMD")
```

Comment: this will always be true `elif Console == "Exit" or "exit" or "EXIT" or "end" or "End" or "END":`

Comment: Hi, please do not post images. You can copy and paste the console output in the form of markdown.

Comment: you can either do  `elif Console == "Exit" or Console =="exit" or Console == "EXIT" or Console == "end" or Console == "End" or Console == "END":` or better still make a list `exit_list = ["Exit", "exit", "EXIT", "end", "End", "END"]` and check `if Console in exit_list:` do something

Answer (score 0):

it is always True, because str as condition is True.

Console == "Exit" (False)

or

"exit" (True)

```
elif Console == "Exit" or "exit" or "EXIT" or "end" or "End" or "END"
```

should be

```
elif Console == "Exit" or Console == "exit" or Console == "EXIT" or Console == "end" or Console == "End" or Console == "END"
```

Or better

```
exit_list = ["Exit", "exit", "EXIT", "end", "End", "END"]
if Console in exit_list:
```

Comment: Or, shorten the list to two elements, and compare using `if Console.lower() in …`.